# Django append query results to query set

Tags: django, django-queryset

in a view I am constructing I need to consult multiple databases. What I want to do is use the results of on query_set to search another db table.

I have functioning **mydb1_query_set**, what I need now is something like this:

```
for row in mydb1_query_set:
        mydb2_query_set = Mytable.objects.filter(id=row.id)
```

So that I keep adding to the initially empty **mydb2_query_set** as I iterate. I realize that there is no `QuerySet.append`, so how do I achieve what I want? Any help much appreciated...

Comment: It might be good to include some model descriptions - because I dont like the forcing of the query to a list - especially in a loop. So depending on the result you want, and what you are working with - it may be possible to aggregate the queries, using annotate, group by or whatever. But for something like what you are using there something like Mytable.objects.filter(id__in=list(mydb1_query_set)) .. where mydb1_query_set is just a list of ids.

This may be totally wrong for you - but i just want to show you for loops and list conversions may not be the only/best choice.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a `list` instead of a `queryset`, and then you can `append` or `extend` as you wish.

```
mydb2_query = []
for row in mydb1_query_set:
    mydb2_query.extend(list(Mytable.objects.filter(id=row.id)))
```

Comment: That is along the lines of what I was thinking, but why do I get a `AttributeError: 'list' object attribute 'extend' is read-only` error?

Comment: but this is slow, don't you force the queryset to hit database in each item ?

Comment: Yes, there is one db query for each item. I was trying to answer the question 'how do you append results to queryset?', not give the most optimal solution. If there were performance problems, then you could try a different approach, as Storm suggested in the comment above.

Comment: I am using `fromList = ThingShareLink.objects.filter(from_share_id=share_id)
        toList = ThingShareLink.objects.filter(to_share_id=share_id)
        context['object_list'] = list(chain(fromList, toList))`

Answer (score 14):

```
qs1= <QuerySet [<User: 1@gmail.com>, <User: 2@gmail.com>]>
qs2= <QuerySet [<User: 3@gmail.com>, <User: 4@gmail.com>]>
qs3 = qs1 | qs2
```

res:

```
qs3 = <QuerySet [<User: 1@gmail.com>, <User: 2@gmail.com>, <User:3@gmail.com>, <User: 4@gmail.com>]>
```

EDIT: Link to documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#operators-that-return-new-querysets

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Comment: **Note** :- It will only work on `querysets with same model`.

Comment: There is a problem with this answer. If you want to filter with date, suppose latest date elements will be first, it doesn't show it correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Using python's built in `itertools` module worked best for me.

```
from itertools import chain

qs1 = Mytable.objects.filter(id=2)
qs2 = Mytable.objects.filter(id=3)

all_queries = chain(qs1, qs2)
```

Here's the docs, in case you'd like some reference materials: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain

Comment: yours would force two queries to be evaluated while `qs1 | qs2` would result in a single query.

Comment: @OmarAbouMrad, I was unable to get the  `qs1 | qs2` solution to work and for my use two queries isn't a problem, but good to have that noted in case it is for others

Answer (score 0):

Django's Managers object [provide a default method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/managers/#modifying-a-manager-s-initial-queryset) called `.get_queryset()` which allow you to concatenate extra queries after it:

```py
queryset = MyModel.objects.get_queryset()
if username:
    queryset = queryset.filter(username=username)
if country:
    queryset = queryset.filter(country=country)
```

You could easily using `.query` attribute getting the SQL, for example:

```py
>>> print(queryset.query)
SELECT `myapp_mymodel`.`id`, `myapp_mymodel`.`username`, `myapp_mymodel`.`country` FROM `myapp_mymodel` WHERE `myapp_mymodel`.`country` = foo
```